# Can I output the elements of a 2d array as user inputs numbers into a HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Gradually working teaching myself JS with a couple books and now am at Arrays. If this question isn't up to standards please ignore and I'll delete. 
I'm sure it is possible to simultaneously output elements of an array to an HTML table as a user enters them but I have run out of ideas and exhausted my search of this site for answers. I have a 3x3 HTML table for now, a 2d array ("array of arrays"). Want to prompt the user to enter a positive integer and load it into each corresponding cell () locations. Eventually I will write code to test if the sum of rows, columns and diagonals are the same. Looking for a few pointers where I need to modify my current code/function. Here is what I have thus far. Appreciate the comments.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function simpleTable() {
    //create array of 3 rows 3 columns
    var myArray = new Array(3);
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = new Array(3);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) //prompt user for input and fill the array
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            myArray[i][j]= prompt("Enter a number for row " + (i + 1) + 
                           ", column " + (j + 1) + ":");
            //need to output user input immediately to a cell in HTML 
              table here.
        }
    }

    }

    //add another function here to test the rows, cols diagonals if sums     
    are equal
    function areEqual() {
    //expand after solving the issue with seeing user input data
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="button1">
    <button type="button" id="nums" onClick="simpleTable()">Enter 
    positive numbers</button>
    </div>

    <table width="100%" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td height="50"><span id="c01" /span></td>
            <td><span id="c02" /span></td>
            <td><span id="c03" /span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="50"><span id="c1l" /span></td>
            <td><span id="c12" /span></td>
            <td><span id="c13" /span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="50"><span id="c21" /span></td>
            <td><span id="c22" /span></td>
            <td><span id="c23" /span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted code seems to be missing some bits at the top to make it an actually working bit of example code. That aside: I'd recommend making the javascript generate that table, instead of hand coding it.

```
// turn a [[1,2,...],[3,4,...],[],...] into a
// <table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td>...</tr><tr>...</tr>...</table>
function makeTable(arrayOfArrays) {
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var rows = formRows(arrayOfArrays);
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    table.appendChild(row);
  });
  return table;
}

// turn a [1,2,...] into <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td>...</tr>
function formRows(arrayOfArrays) {
  return arrayOfArrays.map(function(individualArray, rowId) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    individualArray.forEach(function(cellValue, cellId) {
      var col = document.createElement("td");
      col.textContent = cellValue;
      col.id = "cell-" + rowId + "-" + cellId;
      row.appendChild(col);
    });
    return row;
  });     
}
```

And then you insert that in a placeholder element, e.g.:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="tabletarget"></div>
    <script> /* all your JS including the above code */</script>
    <script>
      var target = document.getElementById("tabletarget");
      target.appendChild(makeTable(yourArrayOfArraysHere));
    </script>
  <body>
</html>
```

This gives you more control over "what do to, how, where" when it comes to updating the table, because you can either regenerate it, or you can add event listeners to each `<td>` you generate, so you can send update events to be handled without ever regenerating HTML, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should re-label your cells so the indeces match your iterative variables (c00, c01...). Then you can construct the id of the cell whose contents need updating:

```
var cellId = "c" + i + j; // or "#c" + i + j, if you are using jquery
document.getElementById(cellId).innerHTML(myArray[i][j]); // if it's not text, you may need "" + myArray[i][j]
```

Comment: If I follow the scenario from the end of the chapters I believe this is what the author was expecting. As the book progresses the methods and code should be what the previous answers submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
myArray[i][j]= prompt("Enter a number for row " + (i + 1) + 
                       ", column " + (j + 1) + ":");
        //need to output user input immediately to a cell in HTML 
document.getElementById('c'+(i)+''+(j)).innerHTML = myArray[i][j];
```

plus, this might not work because in the 2nd column the id is misspelled. `c1l`. I recommend following Mike's solution because his is more flexible for multiple situations. Mine is more specific to your problem. Plus, you should change the ids to 'c00','c01','c02'and then do 'c10' etc. to make it work.

Comment: Thanks! In a previous scenario I created the table dynamically and it works much better. Sometimes the books are not as helpful especially the so called scenarios at the ends of chapters. I'm going to have to read over these comments to understand exactly what I'm doing. As always though much appreciative. Learning little by little.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to post and answer my own question to help another beginner like me attempting to self teach with books and exercises at the end of chapters. The answers all of you provided at some point will be the way to go, however I wanted to maintain what was learned in each chapter. Gradually i hope to advance and want to understand the solutions and the topics. Thanks again. Here is  the code that works for me. All that is missing is some data 
validation for positive integers.

```
function simpleSquare() {
    myArray = new Array([document.getElementById("cell00"), 
              document.getElementById("cell01"),   
              document.getElementById("cell02")], 
              [document.getElementById("cell10"), 
              document.getElementById("cell11"),  
              document.getElementById("cell12")],
              [document.getElementById("cell20"), 
              document.getElementById("cell21"),    
              document.getElementById("cell22")]);
for(var rows = 0; rows < 3; rows++)
{
    for(var cols = 0; cols < 3; cols++)
    {
        var nums = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number for row " + (rows +   
1) + ", column " + (cols + 1) + "."));
        myArray[rows][cols].innerHTML = nums;
    }
}
}

function checkMagic() {
var flag = true;

var sumDiag1 = parseInt(myArray[0][0].innerHTML) + parseInt(myArray[1] 
[1].innerHTML) + parseInt(myArray[2][2].innerHTML);

var sumDiag2 = parseInt(myArray[2][0].innerHTML) + parseInt(myArray[1]
[1].innerHTML) + parseInt(myArray[1][2].innerHTML);
if(sumDiag1 != sumDiag2)
    flag = false;       
//get sum of rows using for loop and check if they are the same
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var rowSum = parseInt(myArray[i][0].innerHTML) + parseInt(myArray[i]
[1].innerHTML) + parseInt(myArray[i][2].innerHTML);
    if(rowSum != sumDiag1) //check if row is same as diagonal
        flag = false;
}
for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    var colSum = parseInt(myArray[0][j].innerHTML) + parseInt(myArray[1]
[j].innerHTML) + parseInt(myArray[2][j].innerHTML);
    if(colSum != sumDiag2)
        flag = false;
}
//output the results to table
if(flag == false)
    document.getElementById("magic").innerHTML=("Sorry, your square is 
not a magic square");

if(flag == true)
    document.getElementById("magic").innerHTML=("Wow! This is a magic   
square");

}
```